# XSLT doesn't select all nodes when their number is greater than one

Tags: xml, xslt

The number of paragraphs *p* is not one. I don't get this xslt to work that it takes **all** of the *p* nodes into consideration. Instead it only takes the first. Furthermore it "mixes them up" with the *i* nodes.

This is the xml:

```
<doc>
  <article>
    <texte>
      <notes>-</notes>
      <content>
        <title>T 1</title>
        <argument>Arg 1</argument>
        <p>Paragraph 1.1</p>
        <p>Paragraph 1.2</p>
        <p>Paragraph <i>1.3</i></p>
        <short-author>FB</short-author>
      </content>
      <notes>-</notes>
      <content>
        <title>T2</title>
        <p>Paragraph 2.1</p>
        <short-author>JD</short-author>
      </content>
      <notes>-</notes>
      <content>
        <title>T3</title>
        <argument>Arg 3</argument>
        <p>Paragraph 3.1</p>
        <short-author>NC</short-author>
      </content>
    </texte>
  </article>
</doc>
```

This is the xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <article>
            <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="doc/article/texte/content">
                <xsl:for-each select="preceding-sibling::notes[1]">
                    <notes>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </notes>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                <title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                </title>
                <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                <argument>
                    <xsl:value-of select="argument" />
                </argument>
                <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="p" />
                    <xsl:for-each select="child::*[i]">
                        <i>
                            <xsl:value-of select="i" />
                        </i>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </p>
                <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                <short-author>
                    <xsl:value-of select="short-author" />
                </short-author>
                <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </article>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the result

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<article>
<notes>-</notes>
<title>T 1</title>
<argument>Arg 1</argument>
<p>Paragraph 1.1<i>1.3</i></p>
<short-author>FB</short-author>
<notes>-</notes>
<title>T2</title>
<argument/>
<p>Paragraph 2.1</p>
<short-author>JD</short-author>
<notes>-</notes>
<title>T3</title>
<argument>Arg 3</argument>
<p>Paragraph 3.1</p>
<short-author>NC</short-author>
</article>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, you need to post the result you want as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I am guessing correctly what you're trying to do here, you could accomplish it much more easily by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/doc">
    <article>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="article/texte/*"/>
    </article>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Notes**:

To fix what you've been doing, you would have to do something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="p">
    <p>
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
    </p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

instead of:

```
<p><xsl:value-of select="p" />
<xsl:for-each select="child::*[i]">
<i><xsl:value-of select="i" /></i>
</xsl:for-each>
</p>
```

Note that `<xsl:for-each select="child::*[i]">` wouldn't work here anyway, because (a) the context node is `content`, not `p` and (b) it doesn't do what you think it does.

P.S. You don't need to insert line-breaks manually.

Answer (score 1):

**Twice as short and simple -- push style only and 1-template only**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::doc|self::texte)]|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```